# Web deploy from Visual Stduio to Azure Load Balanced site

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, iis-7, load-balancing, webdeploy

Setting up publish in Visual Studio pointing to 
https://[my-site].cloudapp.net:8172/msdeploy.axd
does not work as both servers in the Azure load balancer have that address.

What am I missing?  I can't help feeling I'm overlooking something very obvious

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer to create an endpoint with a public port = 50001 / private port = 8172 for serverA and an endpoint with a public port = 50002 / private port = 8172 for serverB. With that configuration, you can publish to serverA by deploying to https://[my-site].cloudapp.net:50001/msdeploy.axd (this will go to serverA:8172). Same for ServerB with https://[my-site].cloudapp.net:50002/msdeploy.axd (this will go to serverB:8172).